# how to write a function in javascript that transforms multiple of 3 into a string

Tags: javascript, function, loops, if-statement

This is what I have done so far but how to create the list of numbers and how to put in the loop thank you:

Comment: As far as parameters go I believe they should be used in your `for` loop:  `for (var x=startOfCount; x <= endOfCount; x++)`

Comment: I do not see `"Mojito"` in your problem description.

Comment: Search web for "FooBar problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
function mojitor(startOfCount, endOfCount) {
    var items = [];
    for (var x=startOfCount; x <= endOfCount; x++){
        if( ( x % 3 == 0 ) && ( x % 5 == 0 )&& ( x % 7 == 0 ) ){
            items.push("Mojito");
        }
        else if( ( x % 3 == 0 ) && ( x % 5 == 0 ) ){
            items.push("MentheGlace");
        }
        else if( ( x % 3 == 0 ) && ( x % 7 == 0 ) ){
            items.push("MentheRum");
        }
        else if( x % 3 == 0 ){
            items.push("Menthe");
        }
        else if( x % 5 == 0 ){
            items.push("Glace");
        }
        else if( x % 7 == 0 ){
            items.push("Rhum");
        }
        else {
            items.push(x);
        }
    }
    return items;
}

var numbers = mojitor(1,110);

var line = "";
var j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    line += numbers[i] + " ";
    j++;
    if(j === 11){
        console.log(line);
        line = "";
        j = 0;
    }
}
if(line != ""){
    console.log(line); //prints the remaining
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an Object with arrays in it to return your results.
In addition, you must install the parameters in the loop counter

```js
    function mojitor(startOfCount, endOfCount) {

      var output = {
        menthe : [],
        glace : [],
        rhum : [],
        mentheGlace : [],
        mojito : [],
      };

      for (var x=startOfCount; x <= endOfCount; x++){
          if( x % 3 == 0 ){
              output.menthe.push(x)
          }
          if( x % 5 == 0 ){
              output.glace.push(x)
          }
          if( x % 7 == 0 ){
              output.rhum.push(x)
          }
          if( ( x % 3 == 0 ) && ( x % 5 == 0 ) ){
              output.mentheGlace.push(x)
          }
              if( ( x % 3 == 0 ) && ( x % 5 == 0 )&& ( x % 7 == 0 ) ){
              output.mojito.push(x)
          }
      }
      return output;
    }

    var result = mojitor(1, 110);

    console.log('Menthe: ' + result.menthe); //"Menthe"
    console.log('Glace: ' + result.glace); //"Glace"
    console.log('Rhum: ' + result.rhum); //"Rhum"
    console.log('MentheGlace: ' + result.mentheGlace); //"MentheGlace"
    console.log('Mojito: ' + result.mojito); //"Mojito"
```